# How do I disable tablet gestures in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I'm using a Wacom Intuos4 and I have recently upgraded to Windows 8. I don't have a problem when using Photoshop however I occasionally draw on flash based online boards. The problem is, when I drag the pen in a direction repetitively (which is basically all I do when drawing) it's detected as a gesture, sometimes causing Chrome to go to the previous page (left drag) and making me lose the entire thing. Is there a way to disable these "gestures"? I believe this is not something caused by Windows 8 (or Charms) because I run Windows in English although it's not the initial language that Windows was installed in. I changed to English long after the installation. When Windows takes a move as a gesture, a small text pops up next to the cursor informing me about what I have just done and those pop ups are not even in English. I'm sorry for failing to be any more specific here but these gestures could be a feature of either Windows (unlikely), the tablet, Chrome or the computer itself. It's an Acer Aspire and it has one of those little stickers on it that specifies some of the features and one of them reads "Multi-Gesture" (referring to the touchpad, I guess). Could it be that this Multi-Gesture feature somehow decided to expand and apply for my tablet as well? If so, how do I disable it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can disable gestures on Windows 8. Follow this procedures to disable touchpad gestures:

1. Before starting the actual procedure, we suggest you create a manual system restore point as we are going to edit the registry.
2. Copy the following registry code in Notepad and then save the file as `Touch.reg` file. Make sure that you save the file with .reg extension.

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Right Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000002 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Left Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000002 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Right Edge Pull Extended Zone] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000002 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Top Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000002
   ```
3. Double-click on `Touch.reg`, click `Yes` for the prompt, and then `OK`.
4. Reboot your Windows 8 PC to disable the above mentioned gestures.

---

To enable these disabled gestures again, follow the given below instructions:

1. Copy the below registry code in Notepad, save it as `TouchEnable.reg` file.

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Right Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000000 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Left Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000000 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Right Edge Pull Extended Zone] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000000 
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Top Edge Pull] 
   "ActionType"=dword:00000000
   ```
2. Double-click on the file, click `Yes`, and then `OK` when you see confirmation message.
3. Reboot your computer. That’s it!

Comment: Sorry man I made a small mistake the last code after step 3 is for enabling disabled gestures

Comment: i really doubt this affects Wacom? these are all Synaptics registry keys. the question is about Wacom